# Roots of a polynomial.

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$$ has the roots $$\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$$ What roots does the polynomial $$g(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}bx^{n-1}+a_{n-2}b^2x^{n-2}\ldots+a_1b^{n-1}x+a_0b^n$$ has?

I tried with a second degree polynomial and obtained that the roots of $g(x)$ would be $b(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$.

I could use a third degree polynomial as another example but it wouldn´t be a proof for this. I also thought induction could be a way but I´m not sure it aplies for this kind of proof.

I´d appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Observe that the term $a_0b^{n}$ is the product of all roots of g(x). If you could assume or given that the roots are all the same, then the root could be easily determined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint.

With $b \ne 0$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b^{n-k}x^k = b^n\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\left(\frac xb\right)^k = b^n f\left(\frac xb\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you @Cesareo

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: While this is elegant, I am not sure how to proceed? Does this mean that $b.\alpha_{i}$ is a root for $g(x)$?

Comment: If $f(x) = a_n\prod_{k=1}^n(x-\alpha_k)$ then $g(x) = b^na_n\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac xb-\alpha_k\right)$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  If $b=0$, you know that the roots of $g$ are $0$ with multiplicity $n$, so you can say that the roots are $b\alpha_1,b\alpha_2,\ldots,b\alpha_n$ in this case. 
 If $b\neq 0$, observe that $$g(bx)=b^nf(x).$$